# addObject to NSMutableArray is nil even after initialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray declared as property in .h and initialized in viewDidLoad in my SPOCVC .m (UIViewController)...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* SPOCTrackList;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
if ([self SPOCTrackList] == nil) {
    self.SPOCTrackList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"SPOTTrackList INITIALIZED");
}
```

In a separate VC, I'm trying to pass/addObject to SPOCTracklist...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


SCTrack* selectedTrack = self.trackList[indexPath.row];

[[[SPOCVC sharedInstance]SPOCTrackList]addObject:selectedTrack];
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[[[SPOCVC sharedInstance]SPOCTrackList]count]);
```

So my NSMutableArray is initialized and I can add dummy objects, but why can't I pass it from another VC using singleton or anything, such as...

```
SPOCVC* spocVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2];
[spocVC.SPOCTrackList addObject:selectedTrack];
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Instead of initializing `SPOCTrackList` in `viewDidLoad`, do it in the appropriate `init...` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers are only intended to be around while they are on screen. They are not a place to store data. Generally when one view controller talks directly to another view controller that it didn't create, you're doing something wrong.

Move `SPOCTrackList` to your model and have both view controllers talk to it rather than to each other.

There should never be a "sharedInstance" on a view controller. That's a sure sign that you're abusing the view controller as the model.

What's probably happening in your particular case is that `viewDidLoad` is running on a completely different `SPOCVC` than your `sharedInstance`.

Comment: You'll want to study Apple's "Cocoa Core Competencies" at a minimum. This particular one is called MVC: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Answer (score -1):

why not use appdelegate to handle this

appdelegate.h

//add property to hold the reference

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *referenceArray;
```

//share the app delegate

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
@end
```

in appdelegate.m

//synthesize the property

```
@synthesize referenceArray;
```

//return the actual delegate

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate {return (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;}
```

in  viewdidload method

//add the delegate

```
import "appdelegate.h"
```

//init the array

```
self.SPOCTrackList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

//Add reference

```
[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].referenceArray = self.SPOCTrackList;
```

and add anywhere like this

```
import "appdelegate.h"

[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].referenceArray addobject:object];
```